# Solr no facet with name [categoryPath] found

Tags: java, spring, solr, facet, sap-commerce-cloud

We have a hybris implementation which is logging a mysterious error on every connection. The error comes from a SolrSearchResult class and says no facet with name [categoryPath] found. it doesn't seem to actually effect anything within the system, but it would be nice to know what is going on and why this is happening. I've looked for the facet categoryPath in the solr config xml's but cant find it. Maybe thats is issue?

```
[SolrSearchResult] no facet with name [categoryPath] found
```

Comment: Yes, apparently it has to be added to the facets Map property in SolrSearchResult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Henrique Ordine. Thats right, the facet box had to be checked for the categoryPath in the SOLR Item types of the HMC